# How to implement Hash::make() laravel method in iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, laravel, hash

I try to make sign up form in **iOS** **Objective C**. And *server side* using `Hash::make()` **laravel method** for hashing. Now i do not know how to hash my password in *client side*(iPhone-ObjectiveC) for suite in server side.
Thank you.

Comment: Isn't it better to send it unhashed through an encrypted channel than hashed through an unencrypted?

Comment: @JoelHinz What let you think, that he uses a unencrypted channel?

Comment: Because otherwise it likely wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: do not know how to do this? i need it.